# How to center the triangle on a popover horizontally

Tags: popup, tooltip, tailwind-css, popover, centering

I am using TailwindCSS on my React project and I'm currently creating a custom popover or a tooltip if you will. Everything seems good except I can't seem to center the small triangle outside of the container. It's looking a little bit towards the right even though I set `left: 50%`.

[image]

```html
<span
    id='popover-last-seen'
    className={classNames(
        'absolute opacity-0 inline-block top-full left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-20 px-3 py-2',
        'bg-gray-700 text-xs text-center whitespace-nowrap rounded',
        'transition duration-150 ease-in-out',
        'after:content-[""] after:absolute after:w-0 after:h-0 after:border-4 after:border-gray-700 after:top-11 after:left-1/2 after:rotate-45'
    )}>
    <span className='block text-white'>
        {standardTime(
            timestampToDate(chatee.lastSeen)
        )}
    </span>
    <span className='block text-gray-300 font-thin'>
        {standardDateTime(
            timestampToDate(chatee.lastSeen),
            false
        )}
    </span>
</span>
```

I believe the problem here is the [`after:left-1/2`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/top-right-bottom-left). I tried to do `after:right-1/2` and it went slightly towards the left. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left#description)

> When position is set to absolute or fixed, the left property specifies the distance between the element's outer margin of left edge and the inner border of left edge of its containing block. (The containing block is the ancestor to which the element is relatively positioned.)

Which means `left: 50%` will not center element but his left border will be exactly at the parent's center. You can see it [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/kWJB2G5hyT) - as blue element has some width it quite obvious it is not centered

In order to center it your need to move element itself backward on a half of its own width

CSS property for this is `transform: translateX(-50%)` (where `50%` - half of elements width, `minus` sign stands for moving backward). Tailwind's [utility](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/translate) for this is `translate-x-1/2`

So your triangle should include `after:left-1/2 after:-translate-x-1/2` or `after:right-1/2 after:translate-x-1/2`

Comment: Thank you! I feel terrible for missing such an obvious mistake lol.